# Dynamic Insert/update based on where clause in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, insert-update, upsert

I have two tables as shown below

**ob_period**

```
person_id     ob_start_date

  1            2007/02/11
  2            2008/05/13  
  3            2008/07/29
  4            2006/03/21
```

**visit**

```
person_id     visit_date

  1            2003/06/21
  2            2005/02/23  
  3            2006/04/19
  5            2004/06/11
```

I would like to update the "ob_start_date" of "ob_period" table with "visit_date" of visit_table

I was trying something like below for update but it can't work as I am not sure how to update with a dynamic value from another table

```
update ob_period a
set a.ob_start_date = b.visit_date
where a.person_id = b.person_id
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

**output**

```
person_id     visit_date

  1            2003/06/21
  2            2005/02/23  
  3            2006/04/19
  4            2006/03/21
```

Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table reference to the second table:

```
update ob_period p
    set ob_start_date = v.visit_date
    from visit v
    where p.person_id = v.person_id
```

Comment: @TheGreat . . . Note that I changed the table aliases so they are meaningful abbreviations for the tables, rather than arbitrary letters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 update ob_period a
    set a.ob_start_date = b.visit_date
    from visit b
    where a.person_id = b.person_id
```